# Forms with HTMX, how to choose where to post?

Tags: django, htmx

Edit: add all html to not talk about csrf

I have a page '/ask-tagname' with an html form

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block additional_headers %}
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/tag_name_entry.css">
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}


<div class="container">
    <h1>Enter a Tag Name</h1>
    <form hx-post="/set-tagname">
        <label for="tagName">Tag Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="tagName" name="tagName" required />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

extending

```
<html>

<head>
    {% block additional_headers %}{% endblock %}
    {% load static %}
    <script src="{% static 'unpkg.com_htmx.org@1.1.0_dist_htmx.min.js' %}"></script>
</head>

<body hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

I am serving this using Django and the views file serving both endpoints is the following

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIRequest
from lobby.models import Users
from django.http import HttpResponse


def ask_tagname(request: WSGIRequest):
    return render(request, "tag_name_entry.html", {})

def set_tagname(request: WSGIRequest):
    tagName = request.POST["tagName"]
    defaults = {"tag_name": tagName}
    print(defaults)
    Users.objects.update_or_create(id=user_id, defaults=defaults)
    response = HttpResponse()
    response["HX-Redirect"] = "/"
    return response
```

when I click on the submit button I get a GET request to '/ask-tagname' with the tagname as url parameter followed by an empty POST to '/set-tagname'.

What I expected is no more calls to '/ask-tagname' and instead a post request to '/set-tagname' with tagname as parameter.

I don't understand where the call to ask-tagname comes from. The only reason could be if it reloads the page on the form submit.

Comment: Update the question with a views file.

Comment: I added the content of the view file. I was quite convinced the post call from forms doesn't depend on that so I am eager to hear what I missed.

Comment: Are you not getting an error in the terminal about not including the csrf_token? You seem to be missing the csrf_token tag in your form. The default behaviour when you don't include it is your view denies the request, that's probably why you're getting an 'empty' POST request

Comment: No I add the hx-Header for csrf, I just added the forms html not the whole document.

Comment: Have you tried using django `HttpRequest` instead of `WSGIRequest`?

Comment: You are including htmx as a static file. Do you actually have the file named "unpkg.com_htmx.org@1.1.0_dist_htmx.min.js" in your project? It looks like you're referencing a CDN link but you're loading it as a static file.

Comment: yes I do. Again the question is why does it make a call to the url it is at instead of the url I point to.

Comment: @mariodev I don't really choose what Request comes in I just know that I get a WSGIRequest so I type hint it.

Comment: but Maybe the problem is partially there, I printed what request I get and used that type.

Comment: In the `set_tagnane`, or even can you try to print request.headers["Hx-Request"]. What does it show?

Comment: I gave up and went back to pure html form. I guess in this case it doesn't make sense to use htmx and also there shouldn't be any problems mixing htmx and normal requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your project for send csrf token , for example in your main template you can pass the next script

```
script>
    document.body.addEventListener('htmx:configRequest', function(event) {
        event.detail.headers['X-CSRFToken'] = '{{ csrf_token }}'; // add a new parameter into the mix
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I am sending the srf token but to the wrong endpoint and I don't understand why it does that. Why would it send a request to ask-tagname. No where in the form it says to send anything to ask-tagname.